# JQuery: zoom text on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to zoom/unzoom a text with animate. The problem is that the text is absolutely positioned inside a relative div and when I animate the font-size the text expands only to the right and bottom. I want it to expand/retract to all sides equally.

Prepared example: http://jsbin.com/welcome/48103/edit

Comment: Does the text have to remain relatively positioned?

Comment: You need to animate top: and left: along with the resize.

Comment: do u need the animation? coz otherwise u could just use plain CSS to increase font sizes on hover in and out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animate using the CSS `transition` property:

```css
.zoom {
  display: inline-block; /* this is needed for inline elements */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<a class="zoom" href='#'>Hover me!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The align in horizontal center is easy. Just add `text-align: center` and it will work. But if you want to align it in middle, you need to use `display: table`, because "only" td is "allowed" to set `vertical-align: middle`. So you have to build a div-table layout around: http://jsbin.com/welcome/48145/edit

Comment: Your solution is also correct for me, but I did not know a pure CSS solution was available. Thank you